# no such element: Unable to locate element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to open a youtube link and then click on the channel but sadly it cannot find the channel link. The below link shows the targeted link with a red arrow.

[image]

So, here is my code, and for more details you can check this [repo](https://github.com/salman-/youtubeAutomation/tree/master):

```
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    driver.laodPage("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFPzE4Twj4k");
    driver.getCurrentURL();
  //  driver.getElementById("img").click(); 
    driver.click("//*[@id=\"img\"]"); //Click on video channel 
    driver.getCurrentURL();
```

But it complains with:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="img"]"}
```

I check the xpath on chrome console and it gives me an array of 21 element, so i thought maybe it is because of it. And then I tried to change it to `"//*[@id=\"img\"][1]"` and it gives me an element, but it still complains.

Comment: After driver.getCurrentURL(); you should wait few seconds so the page is completly loaded and the elements are presents, use something like System.pause( 10 seconds ) or use built in functionnality in the selenium

Comment: **`Driver driver = new Driver();`** and **`driver.laodPage()`**? Selenium?

Comment: @DebanjanB `Driver` is a custom class, which setup and run a `Selenium` driver

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the id "avatar" works:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("avatar")).click()
```